# Detecting whether reverb is present

Tags: signal-analysis, sound

I have two different audio short samples of an instrument playing. If one of the samples has a reverb effect applied, how easy is it to detect which sample has reverb? Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

A reverb effect usually includes an added, delayed version of the original signal.

Calculate an autocorrelation. If there is significant amount of power at delays larger than what you'd expect for a normal-sized room (say, 1/5 of a second), that'd be a good indication.

Comment: reverb is different than echo but *with* reverb there should be higher peaks of autocorrelation at large lags then there would be *without* reverb.  but if the reverb is subtle, i think this can be missed.  other than listening tests, i am not sure of a good automated way to tell.

Comment: I second RBW's note. If the recording is known to have "pops" then it might be possible to do a Time Frequency analysis on that and assess the spread of the impulse caused by the reverberation. This would essentially be a mini room probing.